Excel dynamic formatting for decimal places
I have a spreadsheet in Excel and I want to apply a dynamic formatting as below. In general, I want only one decimal place for numbers in the relevant column. However, for smaller numbers, I do not want it to be "0.0", but rather dynamic decimal places to show the "first non-zero digit" (rounded, if possible). See some examples below.



Underlying data in cell
Displayed/formatted data in the same cell




1.45
1.5


1.01
1.0


0.05
0.1


0.045
0.05


0.00012
0.0001


0.0000021111111
0.000002



Ideally I would like to do this without VBA, but in a worst case scenario I could use VBA.
Thanks!

Have you looked at round() ? then combine with if() to deal with decimals?

I have not, but that could actually be an alternative! Not sure how to deal with the if() to be honest... And also how to combined this with a 1000-separator?

You can use significant figures for this. It looks like what you want is one significant figure.
The formula is: =ROUND(value,1-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(value)))))
More info on it is here: https://exceljet.net/formulas/round-a-number-to-n-significant-digits

Doesn't quite give the same results as in the OP's question. But credit for this formula should go to Jerry Lewis, who says he derived it in 1996 and published it in 1998 on a Google Groups Microsoft Excel site, many years before ExcelJet was established.

As you asked to show the dynamic formatting in the same cell, using a formula won't work. Instead, you can use conditional formatting:

select the relevant cells
format them as General
choose Conditional Formatting from the menu
choose New rule
choose Format only cells that contain
in the rule description, choose greater than and type 1
click Format, choose the Number tab, and choose the Number type with 1 decimal digit
click OK and OK.

Now, everything is formatted with as many decimal digits as needed, unless it is greater than one, in which case you only get one decimal.
